# Length of text affecting link property

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, href

I have a Wordpress site which has an image overlay on the featured image which displays the post-title. Each piece of the overlay is dynamically linked to the single post page. (it's a grid of featured images )

Everything works fine on one line, but when the the post-title takes up two lines, hovering over the image in certain locations, the link is not recognized (mainly area to the right of the text)

css

```
.title-styling h1 { width: 50%; }

.title-styling h1 {
color: #fff;
font: 800 60px/50px "Open Sans";
font-style: italic;
letter-spacing: -3px;
}

/* IMG hover styling */
.box-title {
z-index: 10;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
visibility:hidden;
opacity:0;
transition:visibility 0s linear 0.3s,opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.test-cover {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 99%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
visibility:hidden;
opacity:0;
transition:visibility 0s linear 0.25s,opacity 0.25s linear;
}

.hover-decal:hover > .test-cover,
.hover-decal:hover > .box-title {
visibility:visible;
opacity:1;
transition-delay:0s;
}
```

html snippet

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('col-md-4 col-sm-4 pbox '); ?>>

<div class="hover-decal">

      <div class="box-title">
        <div class="title-styling">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
        </div>
      </div>

    <?php
        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
        $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 750, 560, true ); //resize & crop the image
    ?>  

        <?php if($image) : ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="test-cover"></a>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

The code gets the proper featured image and link and puts it in the article and puts a div overtop which acts as a cover-transparecy with the same link. The title-styling is done that way so I can use absolute and relative positioning for css.

Unsure why this is, I can't seem to recreate the issue with jfiddle.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you can't recreate it, we can't diagnose it since it's intermittent. If you have a link we can look at might be able to see it "not working" and go from there,

Comment: It's on local host so I can't send a link. When i put '.title-styling' to position: absolute, it fixes the problem. But creates a new prob where every word goes underneath the other, no matter how long the word. (ex 'from a' should fit on one line, but 'from' sits on top of 'a') If I can fix this new problem, that would work to!

Comment: the problem seems to be that the text box created for post-title expands the full width of the image, but when a word is too long it goes underneath to a second line. The space to the right of both words becomes unclickable.